# Keys overlapping on vb.net [a macro project on external program]

Tags: vb.net, macros

I'm making a VB Macro that uses F1~F12, and shift + F1~F12, and ctrl + F1~F12,
which must be working in an external program, such as browsers,
here comes the problem, the Shift + F1~F12 part are overlapping,
it's not working (on firefox), it overlaps with the HotKey/ShortCut of firefox,
(because it ended up as Shift+F1+ctrl+v)
any idea to fix this? :(
I'm using visual studio 2013.

```
Public Const MOD_CONTRO As Integer = &H2
Public Const MOD_SHIFT As Integer = &H4
Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312
```

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)

```
 If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
        Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
        Select Case (id.ToString)

            Case "101"
             Clipboard.SetText(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\SF1.txt"))
             SendKeys.Send("^" & "v")
            '^This is the problem part, 

 End Select

    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

 Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As      

 System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

    UnregisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 101)
End Sub

Private Sub Home_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, 101, &H4, Keys.F1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this fixed the problem, 
as part of codes I learned from Joiner from here!
[shift pressed, and automatically up?(to avoid long press and hold)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594758/shift-pressed-and-automatically-upto-avoid-long-press-and-hold)

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

Case "101"
                    Clipboard.SetText(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\SF1.txt"))
                    keybd_event(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^" & "v")