# shift pressed, and automatically up?(to avoid long press and hold)

Tags: vb.net, release, shift

Some help on... how to make it possible when shift is pressed,

then the system automatically released it in split second,

hence even though it is still pressed in the keyboard by the user,

but the vb.net system already released the shift key?

to avoid long press or hold on the key...

---

I'm so out of idea already, hence decided to post a question here after doing some serious researches, please respond if you know some tricks to make this possible...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? What is the situation?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate [StickyKeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StickyKeys)?

Comment: An easiest solution I can think of to solve this one...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23444021/keys-overlapping-on-vb-net-a-macro-project-on-external-program

Comment: stickykey maybe? sounds like familiar with what I'm after, but how to do it on vb...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle KeyDown event and check if `Shift` is pressed.

```
e.KeyCode = Keys.Shift
```

You can work with user32.dll lib and send the key release.
`&H10` is `Shift` key code. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a list of all key codes (replace `0x` with `&H`).
`&H2` means *release*. Type `&H0` if you want to *press*.

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

keybd_event(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)
```

You may want to handle entire form's KeyDown events.

```
Form.KeyPreview = True
```

Here is an example.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.KeyPreview = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Shift Then
            Form1.keybd_event(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Do I need to import something for this? 
it shows some incorrect underlines 
I tried "End sub" on this, but things are still incorrect...

Comment: @Kaozty Put _Declare_ after class beginning. Put _KeyDown event_ on your active form's KeyDown event.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response...
here is another little problem that I don't get at all...
sorry for being so noob... 

https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1.0-9/10292516_854816244534001_4054059025862689093_n.jpg

Comment: @Kaozty Replace `Home_KeyDown(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)` with `keybd_event(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)`.

Comment: This is what happened though...
so I tried to change keybd_event in the earlier comment...

https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1.0-9/1187128_854832974532328_287317454065498872_n.jpg

Comment: another printscreen...
https://scontent-a-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc3/t1.0-9/10367141_854842291198063_9187459353716910761_n.jpg

Comment: sorry for much questions,
this is the last... maybe...
I tried putting a msgbox in, but it's not popping out when I pressed shift... it seems to be not working...?

 Private Sub Home_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Shift Then
            MsgBox("hello")
            keybd_event(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: I believe we are close to what I'm after, but success or not, I decided to mark it, for your effort on responding me :)

Comment: @Kaozty It seems there is another control focused that steals focus to the form.

Comment: ohh, seems like it, as I tried keys other than shift (such as enter), they works perfectly...

Comment: btw, it seems to be limited to on the form only, any idea to make it also functional in an external program...?

Comment: @Kaozty I found solution to this another problem. I edited my answer.

Comment: MAN! FINALLY, YOU SOLVED MY 8 DAYS PROBLEMS!
I ADDED THE KEYBD CODE LIKE THIS, AND IT FIXED THE OVERLAPPING!
THANK YOU SO MUCHHHHHHHHH
      Clipboard.SetText(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath & "\SF1.txt"))
                    keybd_event(&H10, 0, &H2, 0)
                    SendKeys.SendWait("^" & "v")

Comment: btw, if you still have time, can you explain what h10 and h2 are for?